# How to add list of tuple value in list of dictionary using pyspark?

Tags: list, dictionary, tuples, pyspark, rdd

I have 2 rdd, one as list of dictionary and second as list of tuple shown as below -

rdd1 = [{'id1', ['string', 'string', count]}, {'id2', ['string', 'string', count]}, {'id3', ['string', 'string', count]}]
rdd2 = [(id1, count), (id2, count), (id3, count)]

Now i want to add count from rdd2 to rdd1 if id from rdd2 matches with rdd1.
Can you please help me to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Gates answer is correct, you should try to avoid using for loops when working with RDD's. Operations on RDDs are parallelized and are much faster compared to for loops when working with big datasets.You can achieve the same by joining the two RDDs and reformatting the output:

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([{'id1':['string','string',1]}, {'id2':['string','string',2]}, {'id3':['string','string',3]}])
rdd2 = sc.parallelize([('id1',2), ('id2',4), ('id3',6), ('id4',8)])
rdd_joined = rdd1.flatMap(lambda x:x.items()).join(rdd2)
rdd_reformatted = rdd_joined.map(lambda (x,(y,z)):{x:y[:-1]+[y[-1]+z]})
```

`rdd_reformatted.collect()` gives as output:

```
[{'id2': ['string', 'string', 6]}, 
 {'id3': ['string', 'string', 9]}, 
 {'id1': ['string', 'string', 3]}]
```

Comment: Thank you Jaco. You are great. Learned a lot from your code.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.

```py
rdd1 = [{'id1':['string','string',1]}, {'id2':['string','string',2]}, {'id3':['string','string',3]}]
rdd2 = [('id1',2), ('id2',4), ('id3',6), ('id4',8)]

for each in rdd2:
    there = False
    position = 0
    for ele in rdd1:
        if each[0] in ele.keys():
            #now increment the count
            original = rdd1[position]
            originalList = original[each[0]]
            #updating the 3rd element
            newList = originalList
            newList[2] = originalList[2] + each[1]
            #update the new list to key
            updated = { each[0] : newList }
            rdd1[position] = updated
            there = True
            break
        position = position + 1
print rdd1
#output: [{'id1': ['string', 'string', 3]}, {'id2': ['string', 'string', 6]}, {'id3': ['string', 'string', 9]}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It really helped me.